# "Sorry, we have no imagery here" error

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have a problem with google map displayed on my website, which worked very well until last Friday. One of my customers said he couldn't view google map from my website any more and sent me a screenshot which is full of "Sorry, we have no imagery here" texts.

The weird thing is that only one customer has this problem so far. I tried different browsers(IE, Firefox, Chrome) and different computers both in my office and home, but couldn't reproduce the problem.

The customer also tried different browsers on his computer without any change.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="LeftBarContent" runat="server" >
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false">
//<![CDATA[

var gm = null; //google map

function InitLoad() {

    if (gm == null) {
        var myOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(44, -76),
            minZoom: 1,  //minimal allowed zoom level of map
            maxZoom: 22, //maximal allowed zoom level of map
            zoom: 3,
            scaleControl: true,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
        };
        gm = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("divMap"), myOptions);
    }
}

//]]>
</script>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Perhaps your user zoomed in too far, or scrolled to an area of the map where there is no imagery. Try to narrow down the relevant code, then post it so we can take a look.

Comment: Usually when only one person has an issue like this (weird issue). It is the person at fault. Maybe he has some settings on his computer or whatever that's preventing it from working

Comment: The user got this error immediately when he visited my website https://webservice.lotek.com . He did not have a chance to zoom or scroll yet before the problem occurred.

Comment: Was the user logged in and tracking a device that was in a location that was not mapped at the specified zoom level?

Comment: The problem already existed before he logged in.

Comment: Customer just called. It is working now on his computer. He did not do anything. Nor did I. The problem comes and goes like a mystery.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the below meta content in the head section to solve this problem.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' *; img-src * data:'unsafe-inline'">
```

Answer (score 0):

Google maps work with "Map-Tiles" method. In Map-Tiles method the map displayed to the user is built from a lat of small images (usually size 256x256 pixels) called tiles. Depending on the area visible to the user, the client will fetch the relevant Map-Tile for the appropriate zoom level.

In Google Maps, in some areas, some map-tiles are missing for certain zoom levels (usually very high zoom levels), for certain Map Types (usually satellite). For example, you can see these area in the middle of the Ocean in Max zoom level in satellite view.

The way on-line Google-Maps solve this issue is by displaying the highest available zoom level with additional pixel zoom, instead of the proper way, there a different map-tile should be displayed.

However when working with Google-Maps-Api (and not on-line Google-Maps) an 404 error (not found) will received from Google servers, for these locations.

So you will need to solve this by yourself. To do this you can use Google's **MaxZoomService** and listen to `zoom_changed` event. If the new zoom level is greater than the max available, you should set the zoom to the last available.

You can read more here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maxzoom